# Do US literary agents accept manuscripts from UK?

Tags: novel

I am two thirds through writing my novel and just wondered if any writer out there-wannabe like me or published has ever sent a manuscript from UK to agent based in the States.

Thanks
Eleanor

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're writing and where you're hoping to have it sold. Is it more suited for a British or an American audience, and do you want first launch in the UK or the US?

Agents are experts in the rights, laws, and industry in their own country. That's where they know the demands and market trends and have their connections, which is why international rights are often handled by international sub-agents.

If you're hoping a US agent can help you get published by a British publisher, that could be tough. It'll be much harder for them to sell your book in a country they're not familiar with, and harder to keep in touch with you. Forget face-to-face meetings, but even phone calls can get a little tricky with a 5-hour time difference. When they're being flooded with equally good submissions from the US, they may choose to go with the more straightforward route.

If you're looking for a North American publisher and your book has a British feel to it, it's possible that there may not be takers. It depends on what publishers feel audiences will respond to.

I think in general, you'll have better luck with agents in your own country. But I know it can be somewhat easier to research US agents than UK ones. I don't think it really hurts that much to try, and overseas acceptances *do* happen.